# what is the difference between begrenzen vs einfassen in meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone please explain what these two words mean. Translators got result for each two as limit or border.But I really did not understand what's behinde these words.

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/begrenzen and https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/einfassen

Comment: *Einfassen* is to put a border **around** something, while *begrenzen* simply means to place a border or limit. The basic *fassen* means *to catch*, and *einfassen* means to hold something with the help of a border. E.g. a *Brillenglas* is *eingefasst* by its *Rahmen*.

Comment: Please do not post answers in the comment section but as a real answer instead.

Comment: We received a notice that multiple of your questions did not meet requirements for this site. Please take time to read the [tour] and get familiar with our standards. The system will otherwise automatically [ban your account from asking](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), a thing we all don't want. Thank you, and we hope you keep contributing!